# Dask - Is there a dask dataframe equivalent of pandas df.values.tolist()?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am reading a CSV file with about 25million rows and 4 columns - Lat, Long, Country and Level. After filtering out what I dont want, I am left with around 500k rows which i would like to visualise using Folium.

Folium requires the dataframe with the lat, long and level columns passed to it as individual rows in the following manner

```
data = ddf.apply(lambda row: makeList(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'], row['Level']), axis=1, meta=object)
```

makeList is a function defined as follows -

```
def makeList(x,y,z):
    return [x,y,z]
```

The above function takes about 120 seconds to compute. I was wondering if there's a way to speed this up by perhaps using 'ddf.values.tolist()' OR any other way that would compute quicker?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The title of your post suggests that you want a **list**, so maybe a *Dask bag* would be an option.

But your post contains also *Folium requires the **dataframe** with ...*, so more
likely you need to generate just a **DataFrame** with the 3 mentioned columns.

To generate a *DataFrame* with a subset of columns, you can run:

```
data = ddf[['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Level']]
```

Then, you could e.g. save it in a single CSV file:

```
data.to_csv('your_file.csv', single_file=True)
```

(500k rows is an acceptable number) and process it in another program as an "ordinary" (*Pandas*) DataFrame.

Comment: In the absence of a ddf.tolist() option in Dask I decided to - 1. Read the files in and perform the relevant filtering using Dask. 2. Use ddf.compute() to convert the subset Dask dataframe into a Pandas dataframe and then use the df.tolist() to get what Folium requires. This alone has brought the processing down by around 50%.